# Pausing program when using a GUI

Tags: java

I am a bit unfamiliar with the netbeans GUI creation but I have already written all my classes and am now trying to implement a GUI.  My main class will create a gui object.  When the GUI is displayed it will ask the user for an input.  From here I want the program to pause and wait for the user to click the Enter button.  Here is the initial code:

```
MainUI run = new MainUI();
run.runProgram();

//rest of main class code here
```

My GUI class code:

```
public void runProgram() {
    // Code for gui layout here.....


    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new MainUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });    
}
```

In the GUI class I also have an action event to get the input from the user once the enter button is clicked.  This string is then returned to my Main class.  Problem is when I run my main class it displays the gui but then executes the rest of the main class before waiting for a response from the user.  Ive read you can use an action Listener but that is already automatically used when using the Netbeans GUI builder to my knowledge.  So is there another way I can pause the program until the Enter button is pressed?

Comment: yes use action Listener

Comment: You don't *pause the program* until the user responds.  You *respond* to the user action.  That's what an action listener does.  If there are things in your `main()` method which shouldn't be executed when the program starts, those things don't belong in your `main()` method.

Comment: Well its only the object creations and function calls that are in my main.  So are you saying I should only have my main call the different UI's and the action buttons create the objects and make the function calls?

Comment: by the way shouldn't `new MainUI().setVisible(true)` call setVisible on the same object calling `runProgram` ? (I would say `this` but inside `new Runnable` `this` is the runnable :3 )

Comment: the new MainUI() line was automatically implemented when I created the JFrame, so I never really touched it.

Comment: If my whole program runs only after the user clicks Enter, should essentially everything, all function calls, object creations, print statements, should everything be under the ActionPerformed button method?  That way nothing executes until the input is received from the user.

Comment: I believe yes, for GUI programs, main method should only prepare the environment for the UI thread, UI thread takes the rest :)

Answer (score -1):

You may want to use a thread.sleep function above the code in order to wait for the user to enter information. This link may be helpful:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/sleep.html

The only drawback I can see to this is that you must specify a period of time for the thread to sleep so it will not depend on whether the user enters information, but rather on the length of time specified.

You may also want to look into keyPress and keyRelease to see if a user presses the enter key after they are finished entering their information.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `Thread.sleep` for OP's requirement, we don't know when the user will press enter So we can't determine how much the Thread should sleep

Comment: That's what I said...The only drawback I can see to this is that you must specify a period of time for the thread to sleep so it will not depend on whether the user enters information, but rather on the length of time specified.

Comment: hmm "it will not depend on whether the user enters information" but OP wants it to depend on the user which kind of make the suggestion wrong

Comment: airgo my keyPress and keyRealease suggestions

Comment: In my opinion, a wrong suggestion shouldn't exist in an answer even if answer contains other correct suggestions :)